# Not throwing business exceptions, but returning value

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
public void Foo addFoo(String name);
```

This methods adds `Foo` to some structure. In the same time, it checks if `Foo` by given `name` already exist. I can throw some `FooNameConflictException`, but I would not, since I don't consider this as exception - this is something that can happens, and it is part of the business flow of the application.

Instead, I would return the information if `Foo` by given name already exist. What is the pragmatical way to do this? What should I return in case when name already exist?

1. Return `null` - and this is pure ugly as `null` does not means anything and it is not extensible and... ugly.
2. Return `Foo` with some internal status that indicates that `Foo` is NEW or EXISTING. However, we must carefully design state change from NEW -> EXISTING, i.e. I am not sure when this would happened, and may fail in multi-threaded environments.
3. Make new class `FooOperation` or `FooAdding` that compose of `Foo` instance and additional flag(s) that brings more information about the addition process.
4. I may go with generic variant of #3 and have class like `Either`, but then you are bound to two values (left or right).

I see solution #3 as the only pragmatical in this case. Am I missing something?

Comment: At first blush it sounds like this method is taking on more than one responsibility, and should be broken out into distinct responsibilities.

Comment: Why do you need to know that the `Foo` value for `name` has been added instead of reused outside of the `addFoo` method? You also say that the conflict is something that can happen in the normal business process, how does you business handle this case ?

Comment: Are you swallowing your exceptions ?

Comment: You could create an enum with the potential return values like : AddResult.NEW and AddResult.EXISTING. You could reuse this for other similar behaviour and add new enum values if necessary.

Comment: Hey, @Jean, I need to know, as whoever is using this layer may react differently. For example, in case of conflict, I might return 409 in some API instead of 200. And so on.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ no, how is that related?

Comment: In this case you probably need a custom sum type to represent the output of the method. While `Either` is a possibility, I would suggest digging more into your business vocabulary to better describe addFoo and the possible outcomes. It is impossible to suggest meaningful names without the business context.

Comment: I agree with @Makoto that you're trying to do too much in one method.  Make a separate method that checks for pre-existence and use it to check before calling `addFoo`, and put the conditional logic for return values in that layer.  In that design, it *is* an exceptional case if someone tries to add an existing Foo without checking first.

Comment: Thanx @Jean, I am not looking for the names, just the principle. Thanx again.

Comment: @Makoto not agree. Additional method would break the atomicity of the method. The responsibility is clear: add an object. I am talking about  possible outcomes of this simple operation.

Comment: The *responsibility* is crystal clear - you're intending to add an object.  The *approach* requires two steps:  check to see if it exists first, and either add it if it doesn't, or return the previously existing one if it does.  Again, that's two distinct responsibilities; the code to add the element should only ever be invoked if it's eligible to add a new element, and that is logic that can live elsewhere.

Comment: @Makoto not agree :) I intend to "add an object if it does not exist". For me, this is valid, single responsibility. Something like "set age for man if age is >18". Actually, more important for me is to _encapsulate_ this simple logic into one method. Users of this class should simply call one method, and not to know to call more methods, in order to do this logic. Imagine that I need to add more checks - I would refactor single place, not many places.... Nevertheless, I consider your point of view as valid, we might discuss this elsewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

By experience, in your case if the `name` is a key of a `Foo` object, I would return the `Foo` object related to the name if found.

Hence the user of the method will use the `Foo` object returned, not caring if it's a new object or already existing object. If you must know the state of the `Foo` object, maybe add a `state` attribute in it.

Comment: That is like #2, but this gives additional work on doing states right. For example, state may be NEW, and then additional thread issue the instance, and state changes before it actually has been consumed by the first thread.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i'd still go for the exception but include a check if it exists in your calling code.

Thus, your normal business flow includes a check for a name conflict and appropriate reaction. Calling addFoo despite a conflict will then result in an exception being thrown.

If you wanted to, you could combine check + handling + call to addFoo in its own method and probably even let that have an effect on the visibility of addFoo (make it private or whatever works best in your case).

The typical alternative to me would be c-style: Always return a result code and let the calling code branch based on it (success, nameConflict, ...)